# Не видит страницу по location в nginx

Tags: nginx

Настройки nginx:

```
server {
     listen 8080 default_server;
     listen [::]:8080 default_server ipv6only=on;

     root /var/www/localpikabu.com/html;
     index index.html;

     server_name localpikabu.com www.localpikabu.com;

     location /hi 
     {
         index hi.html
     }
 }
```

На `localpikabu.com:8080` все работает. Когда перехожу на `localpikabu.com:8080/hi`, выдает 404.

`hi.html` лежит в той же папке, что и `index.html`. Что не так?

Comment: `location /hi {
       try_files hi.html
    }`

Comment: Загляните в error.log

Comment: Хм, первая версия вопроса была абсолютно другой

Answer (score 1):

чтобы ваша конструкция «заработала», надо:

- либо создать каталог `hi` в корне сайта и переместить туда файл `hi.html`.
- либо добавить в `location` директиву `alias` примерно так:

  ```
  location /hi {
    alias /var/www/localpikabu.com/html;
    index hi.html;
  }
  ```
- либо воспользоваться директивой `try_files` примерно так:

  ```
  location /hi {
    try_files $uri.html =404;
  }
  ```