# NGINX location root

Tags: nginx, маршрутизация, rewrite, location

Нубский, но уже изрядно нервирующий вопрос: как правильно настроить роутинг в nginx'e?

Пробовал:

```
location /test {
    root /var/test;
}
```

Бьет 404-ю на запрос `http://[my_ip]/test/`

ЧЯДНТ

Comment: nginx с таким конфигом будет искать /var/test/test

Comment: @andreymal, тогда как сделать верно?

Comment: либо `root /var;`, либо создайте каталог `/var/test/test`.

Comment: Либо прочитать-таки документацию и узнать про alias )

Comment: @andreymal, думаю, стоит оформить ответом, поскольку именно он отвечает на мой вопрос, спасибо! `=)`

Comment: практически дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/540451/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/575311/178576)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin тогда стоило указать это изначально. В тех тегах даже близко нет моего вопроса, не так просто было найти те треды

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну собственно [документация](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root) вполне объясняет такое поведение:

> Например, при такой конфигурации
>
> ```
> location /i/ {
>     root /data/w3;
> }
> ```
>
> в ответ на запрос “`/i/top.gif`” будет отдан файл `/data/w3/i/top.gif`.

В вашем случае `http://[my_ip]/test/` будет пытаться отдавать `/var/test/test`.

Решений два:

1. Поправить `root`:

   `root /var;`
2. Использовать `alias`, у которого немного другое поведение и, видимо, подходящее вам:

   `alias /var/test;`

   > Например, при такой конфигурации
   >
   > ```
   > location /i/ {
   >     alias /data/w3/images/;
   > }
   > ```
   >
   > на запрос “`/i/top.gif`” будет отдан файл `/data/w3/images/top.gif`.